# error importing certificate to keychain Access, Error: 100013

Tags: iphone, certificate, provisioning, keychain

I am trying to provision my iPhone for development; I followed all the steps the developer portal to adding and making the keychains and whatnot, but after trying double-click the certificate, as it says in the developer portal, keychain access gives me an error:

> An error occurred. Unable to import “iPhone Developer: Kevin Mendoza
>   (RT5V4VKW2T)”.
>
> Error: 100013

also, in xcode in the organizer it gives me an error associated with the keychain:

A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain (all yellow banded looking and search)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

When I got the same error code, got through it by importing my certificate with the following command:

```
sudo security import my-certificate.cer -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

Comment: After doing the above command, and opening Keychain Access, I found the certificate was added, but was marked untrusted. I had to double-click it and change the Trust drop-down to Always Trust.

Answer (score 0):

Do not simply "Drag" your file onto keychain access. click File>Import Item...

And unlock you login (or whatever keychain you are using).

Hope This Helps!

And if you can answer my question.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work for me. The error message was the same.